# Robot Framework Run Keyword and Expect Error

Tags: python, python-2.7, robotframework

I am facing the following issue when executing keyword "Run Keyword and expect Error" in Robot Framework.

First I tried this:

```
run keyword and expect error    InvalidElementStateException: Message: invalid element state: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated  Input Text  ${indFNPatientHealth Link}  RCIGM_FN
```

and it failed. The trace back is:

```
17:44:01.894    FAIL    InvalidElementStateException: Message: invalid element state: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated
  (Session info: chrome=60.0.3112.101)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477700 (0057494ad8732195794a7b32078424f92a5fce41),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
17:44:01.894    FAIL    Expected error 'InvalidElementStateException: Message: invalid element state: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated' but got 'InvalidElementStateException: Message: invalid element state: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated
  (Session info: chrome=60.0.3112.101)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477700 (0057494ad8732195794a7b32078424f92a5fce41),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
'.
```

So I modified the expected error copying the full text including session info and driver info. The updated code is:

```
run keyword and expect error    InvalidElementStateException: Message: invalid element state: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated \ \ (Session info: chrome=60.0.3112.101) \ \ (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477700 (0057494ad8732195794a7b32078424f92a5fce41),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)    Input Text    ${indFNPatientHealth Link}    RCIGM_FN
```

And It failed again .

```
17:31:59.291    FAIL    InvalidElementStateException: Message: invalid element state: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated
  (Session info: chrome=60.0.3112.101)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477700 (0057494ad8732195794a7b32078424f92a5fce41),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
17:31:59.291    FAIL    Expected error 'InvalidElementStateException: Message: invalid element state: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated   (Session info: chrome=60.0.3112.101)   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477700 (0057494ad8732195794a7b32078424f92a5fce41),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)' but got 'InvalidElementStateException: Message: invalid element state: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated
  (Session info: chrome=60.0.3112.101)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477700 (0057494ad8732195794a7b32078424f92a5fce41),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

Thanks in advance for your support for solving this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The string you're trying to catch is quite long, variable and contains line skips. Also, the debug data is kind of irrelevant to your test. If I was you I'd just catch the whole message, passing `*` to `Run Keyword And Expect Error` and then use a partial string match keyword to ensure I caught a `InvalidElementStateException` exception. You may also add your message to the partial check, but remove the variable debug data.

See [Run Keyword And Expect Error](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Expect%20Error)

Something like this

```
${msg}=    Run Keyword And Expect Error    *    Input Text    ${indFNPatientHealth Link}    RCIGM_FN
Should Contain    ${msg}    InvalidElementStateException
```